# Unable to play JW player with multiple bit rates on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, jwplayer, bitrate, jwplayer7

I have a video file in 720P, 1080P and 480P.
I use this code for **JW Player** on Android to play a video that has multiple bit rates -

```
PlaylistItem pl = new PlaylistItem.Builder()
                .file(default_media_url)
                .title(title)
                .sources(list_of_media_source)
                .description("some description")
                .build();
mJwPlayer.load(pl);
mJwPlayer.play();
```

The problem is that its not even playing it.

Does JW player on Android doesn't support multiple bit rates or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Can you get **simple playback** to work with one file as shown in [**the manual**](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/interaction/playback/)? If yes, what happens when you create 3 buttons that each do function like `play480` and `play720` etc where each function itself loads and plays the specific video file?

Comment: yes. Im doing like what as mentioned in the manual. I'm able to pass multiple sources, ie same video with different quality. But I'm not able to get that 'HD' button on the payer to change the quality manually from the JW player.

Comment: What happens if you have only `.title` + `.description` + `.sources` (where your [**sources**](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/#playlist-sources) is array of URLs with labels for sizes like HD, SD, etc)? What does your `.sources` look like? (can use fake filename.mp4 if you don't want to show real URL of video files)

Comment: I got the answer from their support team. For HLS URLs, its adaptive. For other files like mp4 we can have the resolution HD button.